# eclipse workbench selections

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have written one code for getting the source and selected of the part of the eclipse. If we click on the view or editor it will display the object and if we select something it will displayed the selected item.The same way is it possible to get for dialogues and others actions. For example if I click on one dialog it should the dialog name or object. The same way for whate ever object i clicked on the wokbench its hould whats the object.including actions. Following is my code.

```
    private ISelectionListener listener = new ISelectionListener() {
    public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart sourcepart, ISelection selection) {

        System.out.println(sourcepart, selection);


    }
};
```

I got the for the commands. we can use IExecutionListener for the what ever the command they have attached to the workbench. Now I want for actions,dialogues,etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: it's a lot of work.

Have a look at Plug-in Spy code (ALT+SHIFT+F1).  It looks at SWT events and uses the widget in the event as a starting point.  It then has to use its knowledge of how various structures are constructed (views, wizards dialogs, preference dialogs, property dialogs, editors, menus, toolbars) to figure out if there is any useful information.

To do something similar, you would have to look at what builds a specific dialog, or action, and try and figure out how to extract that information.  Repeat for each dialog that you care about.

See `org.eclipse.pde.internal.runtime.spy.SpyFormToolkit` and surrounding classes in `org.eclipse.pde.runtime`.

Comment: It is very useful information. thanks. but I am not getting any information for toolbar and actions. How do I get from this?

Comment: you'll have to do the work.  Find out how it's constructed, where, and by what.